# kohana route for 2 level controller folders

Tags: kohana, routes, subdirectory

I have route like this:

```
Route::set('forum/frontend', 'forum(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>(/<id2>))))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'thread',
        'action' => 'list',
        'directory' => 'frontend'
    ));
```

I also have controller: `/modules/forum/classes/Controller/Frontend/Forum/Thread.php` with name like this:

```
class Controller_Frontend_Forum_Thread extends Controller_Frontend {
 public function action_add(){

 }
}
```

But when I try to access url `/forum/thread/add` I get an error:

> The requested URL forum/thread/add was not found on this server.

What is wrong?

Comment: You are referring to the `frontend` directory in your `Route` defaults settings, but your controller is in `Frontend/Forum`. Also, be aware of case-sesitiveness.

Comment: Thank you. Folder patch in defaults array was incomplete. Now its working.